# How can I make a distorted UV map rectangular?

Tags: uv

I have the following [UV map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping) which I need to make rectangular and somewhat symmetrical as shown below:

[image]

I tried many options in the UV context menu, like *Follow Active Quads*, but I am unable to achieve the desired results. How can I do this?

Comment: To make the Follow Active Quads work you need to select a rectangular face in the UV Editor, or make it rectangular if it's not, then unwrap, or use the UV Squares addon as Evripidis Lalissidis recommends. But as Evripidis Lalissidis says it looks like you have triangles, you need to convert to quads.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your UV consists of Triangles instead of quads, try the command *Tris to quads*.

For these kind of actions i use the [UV Squares* Addon by Radivarig](https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares).
In Github, just press *Code* and then *Zip*.

After installing you can select all your UVs and open the tab with  <kbd>N</kbd>.

[image]

For this example i made my UV into equal squares.
You might notice, that some UVs are weirdly scaled and morphed.
If you have the same problem, you have to add seams in the relative problem areas.